# Data model for subscription based services

Tags: database-design

I am trying to model a subscription based service provider and running into a case of "vapor lock", if you will.  I have defined the following model, where the user subscribes to a Package of various services - each Package level contains one or more services:

```
+---------------+     +-----------------+      +----------+
| Packages      |<--- | PackageServices | ---> | Services |
+---------------+     +-----------------+      +----------+
       ^
       |
+---------------+     +----------+
| Subscriptions |---> | Users    |
+---------------+     +----------+
```

However, each service then has their own user defined settings - and each service may have an associated array of other entities to store the service data.   I can handle each Service's data entities for the particular user, but I'm stumped on the settings table. I've thought of creating a "ServiceSettings" tabled keyed to Users and Services, but that seems a little weird.  That approach leaves me with the following questions:

1. What if they upgrade their Package and get new services?
2. How would new ServiceSettings be set or constrained to only the Services the user has susbcribed to?
3. What if I add a new Service?

Am I on the right track, or is there another alternative that I appear to be missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm confused.  can customers build their own packages by selecting from the services? is it ala-cart or pre-built?  if ala-cart is the packageServices the Options the customer can select from and the subscription an association to the packageservices selected?  If you come out with a new service and add it to pacakges, customers don't get it by default (or maybe they do, that's a business decision)

Comment: The packages will be predefined as to the associated services.  Regarding the issue of adding a new service, I was envisioning the ability to extend an existing package, which would apply to all current suscribers.

Comment: So for example: customer 1 subscribes to a "Package 1" and it may have 5 services.  Customer 2 subscribes to package 2 and it has all the same services as Package 1 + 3 more.  Each of those services within the package have an assundry of settings set per user (or per subscription?)

Comment: Interesting question.  Well, if a user upgrades, and their new subscription includes services from the previous subscription, their settings should be retained. So, I'd say that settings should be keyed off of Users instead of subscriptions.

Comment: Do you _restrict_ settings? In other words, do you have a set of "declared" settings that user must then fill, or can user freely add/remove settings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like your **ServiceSettings**; but only to define the list of settings for each service. The values of those service Settings must exist in either a **SubscriptionServiceSettings** or a **UserServiceSettings** depending on if multiple users can share a subscription but have different service settings or not.  As you add a new service, you must provide default values so that when they are added; the user gets those defaults at first; but can change them to fit their needs. And/Or users need some sort of notification regarding new service settings.

So to directly address the questions:

**What if they upgrade their Package and get new services?**
Use a userServicesSettings to retain package settings and as they subscribe to a package that has those settings, use them, otherwise ignore them; but retain them for altered services in the future (again a business question)

**How would new ServiceSettings be set or constrained to only the Services the user has susbcribed to?**
That's just a join between the subscription, pacakage, packageservices, and ServiceSettings.  (Unless you want to maintain package versions; but that's a whole different line of thought)

**What if I add a new Service?**  So you add new serviceSettings, UserServiceSettings are defaulted (or notification to user is provided so they can fill in what they want, or both) and now you have the needed details.  Defaults are useful in dynamic environments incase people don't make decisions you NEED them to make.  Default values say, you'll get this unless you change it; causing people to accept default or take action.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I'll play around with this structure and see if it works!

Answer (score 0):

Your questions are primarily about change over time.  But your model is temporally static - it does not recognize that data associations may be different in the past or future.

This model is fine for a production environment only concerned with currently deployed subscriptions.  But to be able to do time based snapshots, or to manage service transitions, you must, at a minimum, add timestamps to the packageServices table (begin/end dates for service to package associations), and similarly to the subscriptions table.

**What if they upgrade their Package and get new services?**
Packages need to exist independently of subscriptions.  If packages must include optional services then your model needs an additional sub-schema for 'per customer service configs' with timestamps.  So assuming no optional services, the above model will work:

1. If customers switch packages, you enddate the subscription and create a new record for the new subscription.
2. If an existing package is reconfigured, then enddate/ create new packageServices as needed.
3. Note that pricing should also be its own sub-schema, timestamped, with links to Users, as billing ALWAYS changes over time and must be capable of historical querying.

**How would new ServiceSettings be set or constrained to only the Services the user has susbcribed to?**

Assuming settings are user specific, then you need another sub-schema linking services to user, with timestamps. One way to keep this sub-schema simple is to make it a key/value pair (serviceID, userID, SettingName, SettingValue, Begin/End Dates)

**What if I add a new Service?**

Create a service record, link it with begin date in packageServices, link it to user with begindate in ServiceSettingsUser.